# login module email confirmation process

Tags: php, android, web

I am not very clear about the process, how email confirmation process be handled after user firstly register some website? 
E.g. I register some websites, then I will receive email for register confirmation in my own private email account, I have to trigger that Email link for a success and valid register.
My question is, how is this done? Through the same SessionID or Cookie?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it different ways.

Step 1: Upon successful registration process insert the user details into a table and keep a field (say, is_verified) with default value zero.

Step 2: After inserting the user details, get the unique id (You can set user_id as Auto increment value and use that). Remember to encrypt it so that the user can't guess what it is. Then prepare a link that will redirect the user to the activation script. 
eg. http://your_domain.com/activate.php?link=encrypted_link_is_added_here

Step 3: Send that link as a confirm email message from your system.

Step 4. When the user clicks on the confirm_link, will get redirected to your website. Then on the activate.php, add script to get the unique id from the url.

Step 5: Decode the unique_id and use it to set the is_verified field to One (1)

Note:
In your login script don't forget to check whether the is_verified field is set to one,  while checking login details. Otherwise the unverified users will also have access to the system.

Comment: keep rocking! @taubeistgrossvoegle

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but here goes.

You will obviously have a function that registers the user. You will pass all necessary data to be saved to the function.

Within the function, as soon as you have registered the user, send an email either using sendmail, or user a mail helper class such as PHPMAiler